# Finding a solution to 'ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec' in Serverless deployment of Flask app on AWS Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, xmlsec

**Failed building wheel for xmlsec - Windows.**

I am trying to deploy my Flask application on Serverless and when I deploy using Serverless, it faced the

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for xmlsec, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects

I try reinstalling the packages for `xmlsec` and it still faced the same error. Where below are the installed packages in `requirements.txt`

````
attrs==23.1.0
blinker==1.6.2
boto3==1.26.142
botocore==1.29.142
certifi==2023.5.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==7.1.2
cryptography==38.0.4
defusedxml==0.7.1
elementpath==4.1.2
Flask==1.1.4
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-SAML==0.5.0
idna==3.4
importlib-resources==5.12.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.3
jmespath==1.0.1
jsonschema==4.17.3
lxml==4.9.2
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
pkgutil_resolve_name==1.3.10
pycparser==2.21
pyOpenSSL==23.1.1
pyproject-toml==0.0.10
pyrsistent==0.19.3
pysaml2==7.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.31.0
s3transfer==0.6.1
six==1.16.0
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.16
Werkzeug==1.0.1
xmlschema==2.3.0
xmlsec==1.3.13
zipp==3.15.0```
````